# Make 2 simultaneous ajax calls and call back on completion of both?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make 2 api requests, but calling the second request inside the first's callback function doesn't seem right to me. Is there any way I can just call them both simultaneously and run the callback function only when I got respond from both?

Comment: You could set two global boolean variables as indicators of each request's status, setting each to true in each callback, then checking to confirm if both status variables are true...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $.when() jquery function.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: This is the best solution IMO. It might be helpful to add an example to your answer.

Comment: Thank you! This is precisely what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a variable outside the calls that increments on success. In the callback you test if it equals the number of calls, if true then you can call your finish method

Something like this:

```
var nbSuccess = 0;
var nbCalls = 2;
call_1.success 
  - nbSuccess++
  - if nbSuccess == nbCalls {doFinish}
call_2.success 
  - nbSuccess++
  - if nbSuccess == nbCalls {doFinish}

function doFinish...
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the second request inside the first one callback make them Synchronous. The second will only be called when the first has finished.

If you want two send the two call and handle only when the two are done you may (not tested)
Use the same callback for both and use a boolean to ensure both are done.

Something like (pseudo code):

```
var a1=false; a2=false;
a1.ajax(callback(){a1=true; doAction()}
a2.ajax(callback(){a2=true; doAction()}

function doAction() {
if (a1 && a2) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
var response = 0;

var callback = function () {
    if (response === 2){/* code */}
};

// first request
$.get(url).done(function () {
    response++;
    callback();
});
// second request
$.get(url).done(function () {
    response++;
    callback();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might helps you. Try this.

```
$.ajax("yourUrl",function(){

}).done(function(){
   $.ajax("yourUrl",function(){

   }).done(function(){
       // Do your task
   });
});
```